# Checking for "struct" type in a type switch statement in Go results in syntax error

Tags: go, struct

While learning about the type switch statement in Go, I tried to check for the "struct" type as follows:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func moo(i interface{}) {
    switch v := i.(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("Byte length of %T: %v \n", v, len(v))
    case int:
        fmt.Printf("Two times this %T: %v \n", v, v)
    case bool:
        fmt.Printf("Truthy guy is %v \n", v)
    case struct:
        fmt.Printf("Life is complicated with %v \n", v)
    default:
        fmt.Println("don't know")
    }
}

func main() {
    moo(21)
    moo("hello")
    moo(true)
}
```

However, this resulted in a syntax error related to the `struct` type (not seen if the case statement checking for the `struct` type is removed:

```
tmp/sandbox396439025/main.go:13: syntax error: unexpected :, expecting {
tmp/sandbox396439025/main.go:14: syntax error: unexpected (, expecting semicolon, newline, or }
tmp/sandbox396439025/main.go:17: syntax error: unexpected semicolon or newline, expecting :
tmp/sandbox396439025/main.go:20: syntax error: unexpected main, expecting (
tmp/sandbox396439025/main.go:21: syntax error: unexpected moo
```

Is there a reason why the `struct` type cannot be checked for here? Note that the `func moo()` is checking for `i` of type `interface{}`, an empty interface which should supposedly be implemented by every type, including `struct`

Go Playground full code:

https://play.golang.org/p/F820vMJRum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`struct` is not a type, it's a [keyword](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Keywords).

This is a type for example (given using a [type literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types)):

```
struct { i int }
```

Or `Point`:

```
type Point struct { X, Y int }
```

So the following code works:

```
switch v := i.(type) {
case struct{ i int }:
    fmt.Printf("Life is complicated with %v \n", v)
case Point:
    fmt.Printf("Point, X = %d, Y = %d \n", v.X, v.Y)
}
```

You may look at `struct` as being a *kind* of type, which you can check using reflection, for example:

```
var p Point
if reflect.TypeOf(p).Kind() == reflect.Struct {
    fmt.Println("It's a struct")
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/U8TUogdy6_).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @icza So, could I say that the `struct` keyword is used to create a type (e.g. `struct {i int}` as in your example) but is not a type by itself?

Comment: @Agrim The `struct` word by itself is not a type, it's just a keyword, but `struct { i int }` is a [type literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types), it _is_ a type.